# how to pass some parameter within the google geocoding call

Tags: javascript, node.js, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I have an array of objects with addresses with the four field, field1 is the current location(store) and the rest are address info.

My problem is how do I make sure that I have an result with key:value (store:cords) at the end so I know which store has which cords.

This is the code I have written so far:

```
var NodeGeocoder = require('node-geocoder')
const csv=require('csvtojson')
const csvFilePath='location.csv'
csv({noheader:true})
.fromFile(csvFilePath)
.then((jsonObj)=>{
    convertAddressesToCoords(jsonObj, function(coords){
        console.log('converting finished.');
        console.log(coords.length);
        console.log(coords);
    });
});

function convertAddressesToCoords(addresses, callback) {
    var coords = [];
    var options = {
      provider: 'google',
      httpAdapter: 'https', 
      apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
      formatter: null        
    };

    var geocoder = NodeGeocoder(options);

    for(var i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
        currAddress = addresses[i].field2 + ' ' + addresses[i].field3 + ' ' + addresses[i].field4;
        geocoder.geocode(currAddress, function(err, results) {
                coords.push(results);
                    if(coords.length == addresses.length) {
                        if( typeof callback == 'function' ) {
                            callback(coords);
                        }
                    }
        });
    }
}
```

Current code works fine, I can get for each address the coordinates but the problem is at the end I dont know which store has which coords, since the google geocoding cal is asynchronous so I cannot find a way how to make this work.

Comment: So you want to link the `adress` to the related `coords` right?

Comment: yes that's right @JonasW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping over an array and then calling a callback at the end will work, but its hard to read and can cause some problems, therefore i would use Promises here:

```
const getCoords = geocoder => address => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   address = [address.field2, address.field3, address.field4].join(" ");
   geocoder.geocode(address, function(err, coords) {
      if(err) reject(err) else resolve({ address, coords });
   });
});
```

So now to get a certain coordinate, you can just do:

```
getCoords(NodeGeocoder(options))({field2: "Unknown Location"})
  .then(({ address, coords }) => console.log(adress + " is at " + coords));
```

Now gettig that from your csv is easy too:

```
csv({noheader:true})
.fromFile(csvFilePath)
.then(data => Promise.all(data.map(getCoords(NodeGeocoder(options)))
.then(positions => {
  //...
 })
```

And `positions` is now an array of coord / address pairs.

---

If you want to go with your code instead, just add

```
const currAddress = addresses[i].field2 + ' ' + addresses[i].field3 + ' ' + addresses[i].field4;
```

to keep it in the closure, then you can push it to the results:

```
coords.push({ coords: results, address: currAddress });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Promise. Something like

```
function convertAddressesToCoords(addresses, callback) {
  var coords = [];
  var options = {
    provider: 'google',
    httpAdapter: 'https', 
    apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
    formatter: null        
  };

  var geocoder = NodeGeocoder(options);
  return Promise.all(
    adresses.map(
      (address)=>new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        geocoder.geocode(addresses[i].field2 + 
           ' ' + addresses[i].field3 + 
           ' ' + addresses[i].field4, 
           function(err, results) {
             if (err) {
               return reject(err);
             }
             return resolve(results);
           }
        );
      })
    )
  );
}
```

Then you can use it like

```
csv({noheader:true})
.fromFile(csvFilePath)
.then((jsonObj)=>convertAddressesToCoords(addresses))
.then((coords)=>console.log(coords))
```